# Reuse Git submodule's submodule

Tags: git, repository, git-submodules

I have a Git project. Let's name that `Proj`.

`Proj` has two submodules, `Lib` and `Utils`.

`Lib` also has the submodule `Utils`.

Now the problem is, when one wants to `git clone --recursive Proj`, he will need to download `Utils` twice. When the project grows deeper, the situation may be worse.

So how can I make `Proj` reuse the `Utils` already downloaded by `Lib`?

My working tree:

```
Proj                      # Main project
+-- .git
`-- external
    +-- Lib               # Proj depends on Lib
    |   +-- .git
    |   `-- external
    |       `-- Utils     # Lib depends on Utils
    |           `-- .git
    `-- Utils             # Proj also depends on Utils
        `-- .git
```

Note:

1. It is better that `Utils` stays at `external/Utils`.
2. Due to Windows compatibility, symlinks are not allowed.

I will appreciate it if anyone can help me with such a complicated question.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use some kind of dependency management tool. We don't know which technology you're using, but tools like Maven or npm were made for things like this. I don't see a huge benefit in using Git submodules for this - they only get in the way.

Comment: I'm using CMake for a C++ project. `Utils` are some common header files. Will it be a great pain to migrate to Maven? @nwinkler

Comment: Maven is primarily for Java projects, it won't help you with a C++ project. Here are some links to similar discussions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827705/c-buildsystem-with-ability-to-compile-dependencies-beforehand and http://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/2eiulw/dependency_manager_for_ccmake_projects/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try CMake's ExternalProject module first. @nwinkler

Comment: Maybe it can be done with `insteadOf` mechanism (to redirect submodules to local repository)? Maybe I'll try to make a demo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Possible to use same submodule working copy by multiple projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379818/git-possible-to-use-same-submodule-working-copy-by-multiple-projects)

Comment: “Due to Windows compatibility, symlinks are not allowed” – why would Windows compatibility prevent you from using symlinks? Git is [capable of storing symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/how-does-git-handle-symbolic-links). And Windows, Mac, and Linux all support relative symbolic links, so the link could reference another folder in the project.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned in this nice [programmers-stackexchange-post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114719/organizing-git-repositories-with-common-nested-sub-modules), the only way to come around downloading the stuff twice, is creating symlinks to the first instance of your git-submodule.